Why is the text of this svg displayed at different widths in Edge and Firefox?
I have this simple svg image:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   width="340"
   height="275"
   viewBox="0 0 256 206"
   version="1.1"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="0" y="113" width="256" height="22" style="fill:#a9e780" />
    <text x="15" y="127" style="font-size:8px;font-family:'Verdana'">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,</text>
</svg>

The width of the text is different in this two browsers:
Microsoft Edge:

Firefox:

Why is there such a big difference in the text width? Does anyone know a solution for this? Converting the texts into paths is not an option, as the images will then be very large.
I tried to find the crucial and responsible code part in the svg, I have simplified the code. However, it does not seem to be due to the existing code.

Chromium uses DirectWrite rendering for all fonts.
Firefox uses GDI rendering for "Arial,Consolas,Courier New,Microsoft Sans Serif,Segoe UI,Tahoma,Trebuchet MS,Verdana" by default.
In some image editors that support SVG, you can convert the text into shapes, so browsers won't render them differently.
You can also force Firefox to use DirectWrite rendering for all font by navigating to about:config and searching "gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.force_gdi_classic_for_families".

Firefox nightlies no longer use GDI.

TL;DR: pixel-perfect cross-browser text rendering is impossible
Unfortunately, you're facing multiple problems:

there's no way to get a 100% consistent text/font rendering across all browsers or operating systems because there are plenty of different rendering engines as well as drawing modes or even global user defined settings for sub-pixel rendering
So called "Web-safe" fonts like Verdana are most likely not available on Android devices
SVG doesn't auto embed any font files – when used in an <img> element you may see a replacement
Verdana is highly optimized for readability on low-resolution displays – a generic "sans-serif" replacement will most likely render with a significant width difference

Workaround: don't rely on system fonts

if you're using the SVG as an inlined element in a HTML you can load a custom font by adding a global CSS @font-face rule (or a link or @importfor something like google fonts).
As explained by kazcfz this rendering default GDI rendering in Firefox only applies to well-known system fonts like Verdana, Arial etc. As per Robert Longson's comment next versions will probably change this default.
if your SVG should also work as a selfcontained image resource you need to embed the font as a base64 encoded dataURL – However, this also increases the overall file size significantly. For simple elements like logos I highly recommend a text-to-path conversion as it may still be more compact in file size than embedding a font resource.



body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}

img,
svg {
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400&display=swap">

<div class="resize">
  <h3>100% – please resize</h3>
  <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 256 20">
    <line x1="233" y1="0" x2="233" y2="100%" stroke="red" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    <text x="10" y="66%" style="font-size:8px;font-family:'Verdana'">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,</text>
  </svg>


  <h3>680px</h3>
  <svg width="680" viewBox="0 0 256 20">
    <line x1="233" y1="0" x2="233" y2="100%" stroke="red" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    <text x="10" y="66%" style="font-size:8px;font-family:'Verdana'">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,</text>
  </svg>

  <h3>340px – original size</h3>
  <svg width="340" viewBox="0 0 256 20">
    <line x1="233" y1="0" x2="233" y2="100%" stroke="red" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    <text x="10" y="66%" style="font-size:8px;font-family:'Verdana'">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,</text>
  </svg>

  <h3>Open Sans</h3>
  <svg width="340" viewBox="0 0 256 20">
    <line x1="216" y1="0" x2="216" y2="100%" stroke="green" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    <line x1="233" y1="0" x2="233" y2="100%" stroke="red" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
    <text x="10" y="66%" style="font-size:8px;font-family:'Open Sans'">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,</text>
  </svg>

  <h3>Self contained image</h3>
  <img width="340" src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='340' viewBox='0 0 256 20'><style> @font-face { font-family: 'CustomFont'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; font-stretch: normal; font-display: swap; src: url('data:font/woff2;base64,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') format('woff2'); } </style><line x1='216' y1='0' x2='216' y2='100%' stroke='green' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/><line x1='233' y1='0' x2='233' y2='100%' stroke='red' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'/><text x='10' y='66%' style='font-size:8px;font-family:&quot;CustomFont&quot;'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,</text></svg>"
    alt="">


</div>



Hinting
Simplified: Hinting instructions (specified in the font) can give the renderer hints how to ideally rasterize text. Especially vertical and horizontal stems stay more stressed/crisper when adjusting stem positions to the pixel grid. This trick will obviously cause changes in width.
As mentioned: although hinting instructions are defined in the font each rendering engine or mode will render slightly results – some may completely ignore hinting, others will choose only a subtle stem emphasis.

Top: chromium rendering – subtle hinting; Bottom: Firefox – stronger hinting applied
See also:

Why is my SVG file not using my font file?


This works for me, i created this css
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

